# How to set MS Powerpoint for Mac 2019 to stop the scale to fit paper when printing?

Tags: ms-office, pdf, printing

Recently I find MS Powerpoint for Mac 2019 ignores the scale to fit paper option in print setup and always scale the ppt page to 100% paper size. Currently I change the paper size in print setup to match the ppt paper size to avoid the issue. But it is still annoying. I wonder if anyone has a solution?

Background: I use powerpoint for Mac to draw figures in my paper. Usually I set the page size to the page size of the paper template, draw my figures on the ppt page, export the ppt to pdf and trim extra blank margins to generate a figure. This setup works in windows but is a pain under Mac OS due to the above scaling issue.

Comment: What happens if you use Export (PDF) from the File menu, instead of going through the print menu? That makes a PDF at the same size as the PP page, without 'placing' it on a sheet.

Comment: @benwiggy It will work and generate a pdf at selected paper size, but for all ppt pages. I want to save only one page to pdf.